# Can pressure be negative?

Tags: pressure, definition

From Wiki and from physics fundamentals lections I received info that [pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure) is scalar value. But in definition you have relation between projections of two vector values to normal axe-force and surface area with normal orientation. Are you interesting only in absolute values of this two vectors? (if so then the pressure is always positive.)

Can pressure be negative?

I don't want to discuss the averaged model of the pressure compare to tension elastic model. 
At current moment from the post answers and comments I realized that pressure scalar field can be defined so:

[image]

$f$ is support force to support equilibrium in $ds$ surface under other molecules attack. pressure scalar value in some circumstances can be negative. If smth. was wrong here please let me know!

Comment: Scalars can be negative. Is there a question in here?

Comment: Scalars from R can be negative) So the real question - "can the pressure be negative?"

Comment: Yes. Was that the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define Pressure at A point. Why is it a Scalar?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18255/)

Comment: Please make [the effort to search this site for duplicates](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=pressure+scalar) before posting a new question.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Yes it was.

Comment: @John Rennie: "Define Pressure at A point. Why is it a Scalar?" - Seem it is discussion about pressure vs tension. But I'm interesting in is it exist "sign" in pressure. And for me it is not duplicate. I tried to found a question "defintion of pressure", but I didn't find.

Comment: @bruzzo: Carl Brannan's answer explains this. The force on a surface element $\mathbf{A}$ is given by $\mathbf{F}=\hat{\sigma}\mathbf{A}$, where in a Newtonian liquid at equilibrium $\sigma$ is just a scalar. A scalar can be negative or positive.

Answer (score 1):

Your sources were probably trying to keep you from getting confused when they threw in a minus sign later. Typically you deal with a positive scalar pressure which doesn't have a direction. But like if you're doing a fluid mechanics problem and you've just calculated one pressure and you've got other areas of interest, say the other side of a divider, and the teachers throw in the negative.. It tells you which direction the pressure acts. Also you would typically think of pressures as resulting from a gass or a liquid trying to expand in some container. But as noted here [Is negative 20 psi / 1.5 bar possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90430/is-negative-20-psi-1-5-bar-possible) it'd be reasonable to consider something pulling in on the walls and you could call that a negative pressure.

Comment: So your answer is: "yes, it can be. You take in account signs of projections"? p.s. Thanks for link.

Comment: I can't type equations in latex in comments, so I'll type it in question

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of temperature from statistical physics and thermodynamics we have:

$$P=T{\partial S(E,V,N) \over \partial V} |_{E,N}$$ where P is the pressure, T is the temperature, E is the energy of the system. So the temperature will have a negative value if

1)The derivative of entropy over volume change is negative, or

2)The absolute temperature is negative

As for the 1), i don't know if it's sign can become negative(an increase in volume meaning a decrease in entropy or the opposite). But for the second, there is an enteire research going on for negative temperatures which suggest also negative pressures.

Hope this helps.

Note: See,if you are interest: http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0545 , http://physicscentral.com/explore/action/negative-temperature.cfm , [Showing existence of negative temperature for a quantum system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176656/showing-existence-of-negative-temperature-for-a-quantum-system/176681#176681), [Are negative temperatures typically associated with negative absolute pressures?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38907/are-negative-temperatures-typically-associated-with-negative-absolute-pressures)

Comment: You can also see: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57556/have-negative-pressures-any-physical-meaning. Hope I helped.